# kubernetes nginx-ingress controller Liveness probe failed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.1.1.254:10254/healthz: dial tcp 10.1.1.254:10254: getsockopt: connection refused

I am getting this error in the nginx-ingress-controller when I describe the pod.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-nginx
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: '10254'
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true' 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.13.0
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
            - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
          - name: https
            containerPort: 443
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
```

here is the nginx-controller

Comment: Hi , can you provide the logs of the pod `kubectl logs -f POD_NAME` ?

Comment: Can you check if your pod actually exposes something at port `10254`? It would seem that port is walled off. The two places you should check is:
(1) `kubectl exec` into the pod and check if any processes is listening on port 10254.
(2) Try to telnet the pod ip at port 10254 from one of the node machines.

Comment: there's an easy way to troubleshoot:
- Increase the initialDelaySeconds to 300 (5 minutes or less)
- Get inside the pod with exec -it
- Run curl localhost//healthz: 10254
- Check if you're getting the same error

If you're getting the same using curl, then, your easy is in a container, probably you're not exposing or nothing is listening there.

If it works, probably you found a bug.

Comment: If i remove that its working

Comment: Although the issue is more than 3 years old, I just wanted to mention that, moving forward, if you get an indication of a potential GCP issue, I would suggest [reporting the issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) with [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list), so that the GCP Support team can take a deeper look.